# 10.7 Preview app on 10.13

Tags: macos, high-sierra, preview

I'd like to get the Preview app from 10.7 to work on 10.13. I've done it with the calculator by editing a file in contents folder. I guess the same can be done with Preview app. Unfortunately I dont remember what I did, or which file that should be edited.

Anyone who can help with this?

Comment: wow, ok... Impressive. I dont take it you'd be willing to spent time writing a code for Preview?

Comment: No. :P It was actually an insane amount of work, basically a lot of guessing and seeing what happened. But I left a more complete answer below.

Comment: What error showed up when you tried to launch Preview, anyway? I happen to be looking at the 10.7 Preview today; it launches on Mavericks via a pretty simple `DYLD_INTERPOSE(OBJC_CLASS_$SCNExportOperation, OBJC_CLASS_$_SCNExportOperation);` (Effectively, removing the underscore from the class name.)

Answer (score 1):

If you've tried copying it over and it doesn't work, then realistically there's little you can do.

Applications are *(crudely)* just a series of instructions to the OS. The available instructions change from one OS to the next.  If the app is sending instructions that are no longer valid, then it just won't run.

Your best option is to identify what features you want from Preview in 10.7 that are not in Preview from 10.13, and find a third-party app that provides them.

Comment: Thanks. But I dont think thats entirely true though. As stated, I managed to get the 10.7 calculator to work on 10.13. I did this by editing and remove lines in a file within contents folder. Same should go for preview app. Dont see why this should be any different.

Comment: Apps are different. Yes, the Info.plist does contain metadata about the app, including required environments. But ultimately, those limitations were set for a reason, and it may be that the app will crash when particular features are accessed. What lines did you change? Add them to your question.

Comment: I dont remember which lines I'm afraid. Think it was within the plist though, but agian, I really dont remember.

Comment: I can tell you this, my 10.07 calculator runs just as smooth on 10.13 as it did in 10.07.

Comment: Note that Preview makes much more complex calls to the OS than a simple calculator does - all the GUI rather than just simple Cocoa calls

Comment: True! Yet still, I'd like to give it a try.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Calculator app hasn't changed in functionality in 20 years. Why do you want the Calc from an older OS? Is it simply cosmetic?

Comment: Yes, I like the old Calculator layout better. Functionality seems to be the same though. Which is not the case with Preview app. You might be right that 10.7 version will crash on 10.13, but I'd like to try. Do you have a suggestion towards which file I should edit and what to edit?

Comment: @benwiggy - probably nearer 30 years NeXTStep had a version - and probably the code has hardly changed - although BigSur or Catalina might well have totally rewritten it to use Catalyst so is the same as iOS version

Answer (score 1):

The file you edited was almost certainly `Contents/Info.plist`. You usually just need to change `CFBundleVersion` to a number greater than the one listed in the `MinimumVersionRequirements` section of Apple's blacklist: `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/Exceptions.plist`.

Other options include changing the  `CFBundleIdentifier` in the application's `info.plist`, or simply editing `Exceptions.plist` so the application/version is no longer blacklisted (if System Integrity Protection is disabled).

Before you bother with that, however, there's an easier way to temporarily launch and app and see whether or not it will work. Instead of double clicking the `.app` file, try running the executable in `Contents/macOS` directly. This should bypass Apple's blacklist.

---

I have some bad news—none of this is likely to work. Preview is a lot more complex than Calculator.

If you want to go further, start by using `otool -l` to see what frameworks a binary depends on:

```
otool -l /System/Library/CoreServices/CoolApp.app/Contents/MacOS/CoolApp
```

...and `install_name_tool` to change which copy of a framework is used by a binary:

```
install_name_tool -change /Library/Frameworks/Foo.framework/Versions/A/Foo @executable_path/../Frameworks/Foo-From-Lion.framework/Versions/A/Foo Bar.app/Contents/MacOS/Bar
```

But it still *probably* won't be enough for Preview, either.

Here is all of the code I had to inject to make the 10.8 version of QuickTime work in 10.9 (thereby adding back support for third-party codecs such as Perian, which I subsequently updated to support VP9, the format used for 4K Youtube videos). https://github.com/Wowfunhappy/QuickTime-Fixer/blob/master/QuickTimeFixer/main.m. It took weeks to figure out what code was needed; I finished it only because the pandemic left me stuck inside over Christmas and New Years. And I was only bringing QuickTime one version ahead, not *seven* versions!

Comment: Thanks for your very skilled reply, although its quite depressing news:) Such a shame. I was really hoping to get the old preview app running. Tried tons of third party apps, and non works anyway near as well as the old 10.7 preview...

Comment: Dont suppose it will change anything if I "only" need it to work on 10.11 ?

Comment: @HidalgoJames It makes a difference, yes, it's _more_ likely to be feasible. But only relative to "almost certainly not feasible". I'd be more optimistic if you targeting 10.8 or 10.9.

Comment: What do you like about Lion's Preview anyway? The interface seems very similar to the one I have on Mavericks, just a few buttons are in different places. I'm more partial to the Snow Leopard version, myself. (I have actually tried to get that one working on 10.9 before, I got it to launch but it wouldn't render any PDFs or photos, and I wasn't willing to go nuts like I did for QuickTime.)

Comment: Ok, well, 10.11 is the furthest back I can go. All Preview app versions after 10.7 lacks the hand tool, which is really annoying. Shortcut options has changed too. Overall, 10.7 Preview app is just far superior IMO.

Comment: You can access the Hand Tool with Alt Space. Though with a trackpad or scrollable mouse, it's largely redundant. Foxit Reader is a free PDF viewer with a hand tool.

Comment: Any way to change the shortcut for hand tool?